# How do I make a filter pane appear as a Drop down menu in Qlik Sense?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am a beginner using Qlik Sense Desktop to make a panel which (ideally) should be as similar as possible to another panel. The panel I am trying to mimic has an option of what I believe to be a filter pane presented as a drop down menu. The figure below (the texts are in Portuguese) shows what I am trying to mimic, and was taken from [here](https://www.tjmg.jus.br/portal-tjmg/institucional/nugepnac/nac/painel.htm), after you click in "Visão Geral":

[image: filter drop down]

I know I have the option of creating a filter pane one tile high. This way, the field name would be displayed and when the user click it the values will be shown. However, if possible, I would like something closer to what was shown in the Figure. I tried installing Vizlib library as suggested [in this post](https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/How-to-create-drop-down-menu-for-filter-pane/m-p/1572493#M133526), but the filter style remains the same.

How can I make a filter pane appear as a Drop down menu in Qlik Sense? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [Variable Input object](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/DashboardBundle/variable-input.htm), a [variable](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Variables/use-variables-expression.htm), the [`Concat()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/StringAggregationFunctions/concat.htm), and [Set Analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) to achieve this.

The basic idea is that the Variable Input object will be in Dropdown mode with a list of all the available values of the `[Setor]` field, the selection of which will update our variable, which will be expanded in a set expression in each chart measure that we want to affect with this dropdown.

#### Step 1: Create a new variable called `vDropdown` and set the default value to `Todos`.

[image: Screenshot of the Qlik Sense variable dialog screen]

#### Step 2: Add a new Variable Input object to your sheet.

Under the **Variable** tab, choose our new variable from the list, then select the **Dropdown** option.

Under the **Values** tab, choose the **Dynamic** option. In the box below it, add this expression:

```
='*~Todos|' & Concat(all distinct [Setor] & '~' & [Setor], '|')
```

Here's what this is doing:

- The `*~Todos|` part is using the asterisk as the wildcard character as the underlying value and the word Todos as the displayed value. The asterisk wildcard character will be useful to us when we get to the set analysis step.
- The `Concat(all distinct [Setor] & '~' & [Setor], '|')` part is using the `Concat()` function to combine the `all` of the `distinct` values of `[Setor]` separated with the pipe character `|`. The tilde character `~` is used here to separate the underlying values with the displayed values (this only really matters with the first thing we did).

#### Step 3: Add the set expression to the chart measures that you want to be affected by the dropdown.

Use this expression:

```
{<[Setor]={"$(=Coalesce(EmptyIsNull('$(vDropdown)'), '*'))"}>}
```

So you would use it like this:

```
=Sum({<[Setor]={"$(=Coalesce(EmptyIsNull('$(vDropdown)'), '*'))"}>} [Processos])
```

Here we are using our `vDropdown` variable [inside of a set expression](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-modifiers-dollar-sign-expansions.htm). Basically what it's doing is to set the `[Setor]` field to whatever is selected in our dropdown unless our variable is `NULL`, in which case it just returns an asterisk `*`. This works for us because when you use an asterisk in set analysis (like this --> `"*"`) then you're basically telling Qlik to return "all non-`NULL` values."

That should be enough to make it work:

[image: GIF of screengrab of Qlik Sense dashboard with Variable Input object as a single-value selector]

Comment: I learned a lot about Qlik from this answer, thanks!